# "New company financial settings" link is not found in openerp7. Is it a bug?

Tags: odoo

I would like to map the present accounts to one of the COAs and create a new account list for a new company created. I used to do this under **Accounting**  -> **Configuration** -> **New company financial settings**. But, i could not find the same in openerp 7. Am i missing some configuration or is it a bug with openerp7. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In openerp 7, you can find this settings under Settings > Configuration > Accounting
Select the company in the settings, then you will be able to select fiscal year, account template etc. then click on apply button.